# If I turn Messaging on will it say on another device that is has been turned on

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have login access to my daughters iCloud through my phone
and I was told I could moniter her activity,[image: setting I am thinking about]

- It's already on via this device but If I turned it on another
  device would it email/ pop up message when she goes to iMessage? I don't want
  to confuse her with iCloud or anything before i turn it on
  (Will it email/say that iMessage has been turned on, like the
  find my disabled email)

Thank you.

Comment: Yes I believe it will tell you, but only when you sign into iMessages onto the other device.

Comment: @AVelj Hello Thank you for replying! I am already logged in via iCloud and iMessage, but it's off on the other device from that setting, If I turn on the switch would it alert then, or is it only when a device signs on?

Comment: Can't provide a concrete answer with citations, but just tested my old iPhone 6, switched messages off, then back on. No notification anywhere else. I think it's only when signing in - that *will* alert on every connected device.